# Installing pyfasttext on windows

Tags: python-3.x, fasttext

I tried to install pyfasttext on windows 10 under python 3.6 as explained [here](https://github.com/vrasneur/pyfasttext).
I have g++ from mingw, clang LLVM 7.0.1 and put both of them on environment variable.
I set `USE_CYSIGNALS=0` because I'm on windows.
But when I run the command:

```
python setup.py install
```

I got the following error:

```
File "setup.py", line 66, in build_extensions
    if 'clang' in self.compiler.compiler[0]:
AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler'
```

Can anyone help me on this, I want to be able to use pyfasttext on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't read very well docs from github that says:

```
Warning! pyfasttext is no longer maintained: 
use the official Python binding from the fastText repository:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python
```

So I only need to install fastText instead.

```
pip install fastText
```

Answer (score 0):

pyfasttext is not supported on Windows as CYSIGNALS isnot compiled for Windows.