# Got error on installing pyfastext on Mac: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, fasttext

I just got an error on installing pyfasttext.

```
cogent@MBP: pip install --user pyfasttext
```

And then I got these:

> Collecting pyfasttext
>         Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/ef/90606442481d1e4ab10eba8c2b2c449ceaa70c60e9b8d5898bb7504e3634/pyfasttext-0.4.6.tar.gz (244kB)
>           100% |████████████████████████████████| 245kB 224kB/s 
>       Requirement already satisfied: future in /Users/cogent/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyfasttext) (0.18.1)
>       Requirement already satisfied: cysignals in /Users/cogent/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyfasttext) (1.10.2)
>       Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pyfasttext) (1.8.0rc1)
>       Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.28 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cysignals->pyfasttext) (0.29.13)
>       Installing collected packages: pyfasttext
>         Running setup.py install for pyfasttext ... error
>           Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/gm/kpbf6gyx1dx_167zbp2gmdym0000gn/T/pip-install-wuuXwu/pyfasttext/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/gm/kpbf6gyx1dx_167zbp2gmdym0000gn/T/pip-record-Qtcina/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
>           running install
>           running build
>           running build_ext
>           building 'pyfasttext' extension
>           creating build
>           creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
>           creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src
>           creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src/fastText
>           creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src/fastText/src
>           cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -iquote . -include src/custom_exit.h -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Isrc -I/Users/cogent/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/cysignals -I. -Isrc/variant/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c src/pyfasttext.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src/pyfasttext.o -Wno-sign-compare -std=c++0x
>           In file included from src/pyfasttext.cpp:53:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85:
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:534:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register PyObject *obj,     /* Object */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:553:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register PyObject *obj      /* Object */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:575:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register const wchar_t *w,  /* wchar_t buffer */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:593:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register wchar_t *w,        /* wchar_t buffer */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           In file included from src/pyfasttext.cpp:53:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:94:
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:173:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register PyObject *obj,     /* string or Unicode object */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:174:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register char **s,          /* pointer to buffer variable */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:175:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register Py_ssize_t *len    /* pointer to length variable or NULL
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           In file included from src/pyfasttext.cpp:676:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1760:
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
>           #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
>            ^
>           8 warnings generated.
>           In file included from src/pyfasttext.cpp:53:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85:
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:534:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register PyObject *obj,     /* Object */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:553:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register PyObject *obj      /* Object */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:575:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register const wchar_t *w,  /* wchar_t buffer */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:593:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register wchar_t *w,        /* wchar_t buffer */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           In file included from src/pyfasttext.cpp:53:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:94:
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:173:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register PyObject *obj,     /* string or Unicode object */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:174:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register char **s,          /* pointer to buffer variable */
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:175:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
>               register Py_ssize_t *len    /* pointer to length variable or NULL
>               ^~~~~~~~~
>           In file included from src/pyfasttext.cpp:676:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17:
>           In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1760:
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
>           #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
>            ^
>           8 warnings generated.
>           cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -iquote . -include src/custom_exit.h -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Isrc -I/Users/cogent/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/cysignals -I. -Isrc/variant/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c src/fasttext_access.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src/fasttext_access.o -Wno-sign-compare -std=c++0x
>           src/fasttext_access.cpp:43:1: error: non-type template argument is not a pointer to member constant
>           ALLOW_METHOD_ACCESS(FastText, bool, checkModel, std::istream&);
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/private_access.h:55:38: note: expanded from macro 'ALLOW_METHOD_ACCESS'
>             template struct rob
>                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/fasttext_access.cpp:54:1: error: non-type template argument is not a pointer to member constant
>           ALLOW_CONST_METHOD_ACCESS(Dictionary, int32_t, find, const std::string&);
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/private_access.h:59:38: note: expanded from macro 'ALLOW_CONST_METHOD_ACCESS'
>             template struct rob
>                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/fasttext_access.cpp:55:1: error: non-type template argument is not a pointer to member constant
>           ALLOW_CONST_METHOD_ACCESS(Dictionary, void, pushHash, std::vector&, int32_t);
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/private_access.h:59:38: note: expanded from macro 'ALLOW_CONST_METHOD_ACCESS'
>             template struct rob
>                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/fasttext_access.cpp:56:1: error: non-type template argument is not a pointer to member constant
>           ALLOW_METHOD_ACCESS(Dictionary, void, initTableDiscard, );
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/private_access.h:55:38: note: expanded from macro 'ALLOW_METHOD_ACCESS'
>             template struct rob
>                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/fasttext_access.cpp:57:1: error: non-type template argument is not a pointer to member constant
>           ALLOW_METHOD_ACCESS(Dictionary, void, initNgrams, );
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           src/private_access.h:55:38: note: expanded from macro 'ALLOW_METHOD_ACCESS'
>             template struct rob
>                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           5 errors generated.
>           error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

```
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/gm/kpbf6gyx1dx_167zbp2gmdym0000gn/T/pip-install-wuuXwu/pyfasttext/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/gm/kpbf6gyx1dx_167zbp2gmdym0000gn/T/pip-record-Qtcina/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gm/kpbf6gyx1dx_167zbp2gmdym0000gn/T/pip-install-wuuXwu/pyfasttext/
```

Why I got these message? Any idea？ Thanks for much!

Answer (score 1):

Accourding to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004059/installing-pyfasttext-on-windows), PyFastText is no longer maintained.

You can instead use:

```
pip install fastText
```

Comment: Thanks，I has tried fasttext version, it works.  But the project was based on pyfasttext,  I have to run up with it, and try to find out the root cause from some history issue which puzzled us for a long time. So you know how why it failed on setting up? thanks again~